# Non-static method mysqli_result::fetch_array() cannot be called statically

Tags: php, mysqli

Since moving to PHP 8 the code below now gives me the error 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Non-static method mysqli_result::fetch_array() cannot be called statically...'

```
if (!isset($isone)) { 
$seestuno=isset($_POST['seestuno']);
}

if (isset($seestuno)) {   

include ('/home/username/private/dblon.php'); //database connection ($dbcnx below)

$sql="SELECT stuno,fname,lname FROM Studetails WHERE stuno=$seestuno";

$result=@mysqli_query($dbcnx, $sql); 

$row=@mysqli_result::fetch_array($result); //I changed from mysql_fetch_array. I believe this is more correct?
```

The bottom line gives the error. I thought this was basic stuff (since I did it) so can anyone help me out? Many thanks.

Comment: `fetch_array` is an instance method so you can't call it statically. Call it on the object you received from `mysqli_query()`

Comment: And how would I do that? I don’t even understand what ‘statically’ means here...

Comment: Have you read the PHP documentation or any tutorials?

Comment: *I don’t even understand what ‘statically’ means here* - please learn some OOP basics yourself. And I bag you don't ask what OOP is!

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_result::fetch_array ( int $mode = MYSQLI_BOTH )` is the method signature for the [method "fetch_array" of the mysqli_result class](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php). Therefore, you'd have to call it as an object method:

```php
$row = $result->fetch_array();
```

Or, of course, you use the equivalent to mysql_fetch_array instead:

```php
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

There are examples at the bottom of the official docs for that. The rest of your code uses mysqli's procedural interface, so I'd stick to the later case unless all mysqli calls are [converted to object oriented style](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php).

Answer (score 0):

`::` is a scope resolution operator and is used to access static and constant members of a **class**.

`fetch_array()` is not a static method. You can't access it statically. It is an instance method that can be called on every **object**.

To call a method on an object you have to use object operator `->`.

When you fix your code, it should look something like this:

```
if (!isset($isone)) {
    $seestuno = isset($_POST['seestuno']);
}

if (isset($seestuno)) {
    include '/home/username/private/dblon.php'; //database connection ($dbcnx below)

    $stmt = $dbcnx->prepare("SELECT stuno,fname,lname FROM Studetails WHERE stuno=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $seestuno);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $row = $result->fetch_array($result);
}
```